# Woocommerce checkout breadcrumbs

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using woocommerce with flatsome theme. My website is in Spanish, and I am quite happy with how its translated automatically, but I have one issue. The checkout has the breadcrumbs in English. Any way I can add a snippet to change;

```
Shopping cart -> Carrito
Checkout details -> Detalles de pago
Order complete -> Pedido completado
```

Thanks

[image: breadcrumb image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out how to do it, I hope this can help someone else;

```
add_filter( 'gettext', function ( $strings ) {
    /**
     * Holding translations/changes.
     * 'to translate' => 'the translation or rewording'
     */
    $text = array(
        'SHOPPING CART' => 'CARRITO',
        'CHECKOUT DETAILS'   => 'DETALLES DE PAGO',
        'ORDER COMPLETE'   => 'PAGO COMPLETADO',
    );

    $strings = str_ireplace( array_keys( $text ), $text, $strings );

    return $strings;
}, 20 );
```